# Create a box separator

Tags: html, css

Firstly, I want the black right-border to be a few pixels to the right of the box so its not stuck to it (so it acts like a divider).

Secondly, I want it so the last div does not have the border, but every other one does, so there should only be 2 right borders.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

How can I do this?

What I have tried so far is adding padding to the boxes to space the border, but that didn't work, and I also considered using div:last-child, but that did not work either

Comment: Sorry It looks like that was my old post that u edited .. i mean this one is the current question^T

Comment: I'm sorry, but you seem like you are giving a command, you don't explain what you've done and what didn't work. Consider re-phrasing your question

Comment: To prevent the last border, you need `div:last-of-type { border: none; }`

Comment: Could you let us know what is not working with the answer given, so we will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `background-clip: content-box` and `div:last-of-type { border: none; }`. Background-clip keeps the background from using the padding area.

Here's the full CSS (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d6p5u1f/1/)):

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

div:last-of-type {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo element, like this, where you give all but the first a "left border".

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
div ~ div::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left:  -24px;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using a non-repeating background image instead of a color, and set its desired size:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, red);
  background-size: 60px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: left;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```